# Cache images without display using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Loader library to async load images from the web.

I would like to store the images in the disk cache without display them, so that even if the user become offline, the images are still available locally when necessary.

So, how can I save images in cache without display them?

I have tried this, but it seems not working:

```
DisplayImageOptions opts = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(url, opts, null);
```

Comment: you can write your own classes for that, just create a class for memory cache which holds string id and bitmap in Map, just put and get operation. another class for the fileCache which will creating a file on cache dir. and then just write loader class which will downloading images from the web and caheing them on disk..

Answer (score 0):

I have used a library called tantalum. Its a cross platform library for J2ME and Android. It has excellent caching mechanism. You may use it for your application. More details can be found at-

https://github.com/TantalumMobile/Tantalum

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library from Square:

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .fetch();
```

This code simply downloads and caches an image without displaying it.

Comment: The problem with Picasso is that if the user is offline, it does not load the image from the disk. For example: `Picasso.with(ctx).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.my_placeholder).into(imageView)` it displays the placeholder even if the image is in disk cache :(

Answer (score -1):

The main idea of Universal Image Loader library  is to async downloading of images and **showing** them inside View. Cashing is one of the library's feature. If you need to cache images without showing them, you should not use Universal Image Loader. Just write a simple AsyncTask class which will download images to the disk. 
Here is the example of function which downloads image, just call it in doInBackGround of your AsyncTask for all images you want to download.

```
private void downloadImagesToSdCard(String downloadUrl,String imageName)
{
try
{
        URL url = new URL(downloadUrl); //you can write here any link

    File myDir =  new File("/sdcard"+"/"+Constants.imageFolder);
    //Something like ("/sdcard/file.mp3")


    if(!myDir.exists()){
        myDir.mkdir();
        Log.v("", "inside mkdir");

    }

    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = imageName;
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 

         /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
       HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)ucon;
      httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      httpConn.connect();

      if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
       inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
      }

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
       // InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int size = 1024*1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[size];
        int byteRead;
        while (((byteRead = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1)) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
            bytesDownloaded += byteRead;
        }
        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */

        fos.close();

}catch(IOException io)
{
    networkException = true;
    continueRestore = false;
}
catch(Exception e)
{   
    continueRestore = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```